# Mapping the latitude longitude co-ordinates on Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, maps, visualization

I have a list of 1000 locations in a certain city. The location information is available in the form of a csv file in the form:(Name, latitude, longitude). I need to plot the same on a map of the city.

I have started learning d3 for the past two days using [this excellent](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/) guide.I'm not sure if D3 is the right tool to create the visualization. I started using this because later I would like to create few dynamic visualization using the location -like when a user clicks on a certain location and I would highlight other locations that are within a distance of 'X' Miles, draw a line between two different locations, etc.. Is D3, the right tool to achieve this ? And I would like some recommendation on what(new tools, library etc...) I should ramp up for the same. Thanks SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using D3 for a while, but just for doing simple graphics (lineCharts, barCharts).

In order to use the information, I will recommend you to use JSON format to store the CSV data in an object.

I have found this example on the web, by the creator of D3: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Hope it help you a little, it will be nice if you put some fiddle when the work is done